# core data, how get entity id

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

i tried get entity ID like that:

```
NSLog(@"entity id: %@",[channel objectID]);
```

but in this case id is not number

output:

```
2011-09-11 20:40:39.932 n[3591:207] entity id: 0x591f6f0 <x-coredata://4FE0AAD6-289E-404D-B81A-0FC0917BE025/Channel/p3>
```

why it not returns `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A managed object ID is a form of URI that uniquely identifies a managed object as residing within a particular persistent store.

It breaks down as:

```
protocol://persistent-store-uuid/entity-name/object-num
```

… because you can have many persistent stores with objects of the same entity stored in each, the ID for a managed object must include the store.

You save managedObjectIDs as attributes by converting them to their URI representation and setting the attribute to the resulting URL.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it return 3? `objectID` returns a `NSManagedObjectID` which has to uniquely identify your object.

Comment: becouse in another class i have number and for example this code work 

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"packet = %@", [packet objectID]`

Comment: You don't have a managed object attribute called objectID do you? That is a bad idea.

Comment: i known, but otherwise I can not. I try set channel object to `like` table, if channel already exist into `like` table I do not want set again this object

Comment: Well, you can compare on the objectID as it is currently returned, then, this will be the same for the same object.